# The download /back-up of Google scripts (.gs files) bounded to Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have google spreadsheets having Google scripts (.gs files) bounded to it. When I download them from Google Drive, only csv or xlsx get downloaded. The associated scripts files (.gs files) are not downloaded. However the standalone scripts can be downloaded from Google Drive. How can the back up of Google scripts (.gs files) bounded to Google Spreadsheets can be taken? How can they be downloaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can back up file-bound scripts locally on your machine using the [command line tools for Google Apps Script (clasp)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp).

The `clasp` is an open-source tool, provided by Google, to interact with Google App script projects. It may be used, for instance, to develop websites or Google Docs plugins locally instead of using the web environment. You can use `clasp` to download or to deploy projects to the Google App Scritps.
You may check a tutorial in a the [Google codelab for Clasp](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/clasp/#0).

---

**Making a copy of a Google Apps Script project**

1. To use `clasp`, you must install first Node-js. You can download an installer for Windows or Linux from the official website

   - [Node.js download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. One installed Node.js, you must install `clasp`. Using a command line terminal, you may execute `npm` to perform the installation

   ```
   npm install -g @google/clasp
   ```
3. After installing `clasp`, you can download the project files using the script id. You can go to Google Script Editor and copy the **Script Id** under **File -> Project properties.**

[image: GAS project properties page]

4. On your computer, create a folder for the project and navigate into the newly created folder. You can use a File Explorer to create the folder. Using Windows, Linux or Mac, you can create the folder using the command line terminal and the following commands:

   ```
   mkdir gas-project 
   cd gas-project
   ```
5. Finally, to make the copy, you must execute the following command, where 'scriptid' is the id you copied from Project properties.

   ```
   clasp clone <scriptid>
   ```

Once you have a local copy of the files, you can run `clasp pull` to update the code locally or `clasp push` to send any locally-made changes to the server.

Comment: Would you please elaborate this for windows os?

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on how to install Node and NPM from Windows command line http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows .  After this step is complete, just follow the instructions on clasp github page to install it via NPM https://github.com/google/clasp The commands for creating and selecting a folder are the same in Windows and Mac OS. The steps for opening the command line prompt are different in each version of Windows.

Comment: Where are you stuck, exactly?

Comment: Don't forget to do: 
clasp login 
before cloning anything!