# Best development setup for developing gmail add-ons locally?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

It is hard to code with at [google script](http://script.google.com). The word completions and suggestion are poor. Hence I started using [clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) to develop gmail add-ons locally. Do we have any other modules to make add-on development easier ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation. For example, I develop applications of GAS using https://github.com/tanaikech/ggsrun

Comment: Cool. Let me check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is coming a little late but it might be helpful for others looking for a start development a Gmail add-on. I've written a blog post explaining my attempt at creating a sane add-on environment user Webpack, TypeScript, and Clasp.

https://labs.clio.com/a-modern-gmail-add-on-build-process-3dd7aad111f5

Good luck!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I wish you had answered earlier! Thanks Jef.