# Testing Google Apps Script using Google Cloud APIs

Tags: google-apps-script, testing, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I am working on implementing a Google App Script project which makes use of various cloud APIs like Big Query, Cloud SQL, Google Ads etc. Implementation works pretty well through a project where GCP project ID is configured.

But I would like to have a development only version which I can use for my validation.

If I use a test deployment as mentioned on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons, it works. But this works only via the script project where GCP project is configured. For other, it gives "Google developers console API activation" error.

So question here is - is it mandatory to provide the GCP project ID even for test deployments? Is there any configuration that I can use for getting around this problem?

Please note - I can always create a test deployment from the production version of App Script project (where GCP project id is added). But I would like to maintain 2 versions possibly without having to add GCP project in development version.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you or your team have designed the solution. Also it's depends on if the solution is requiring users to authorize all the scopes, if it's using a service account, among other factors.

One design might be based on the use of a single Google Cloud Platform standard project to handle all the OAuth authorizations.

Another design might be based on using two or more Google Cloud Platform projects. I.E. you could use a default project for Google Apps Script and a standard project another for the Google APIs like BigQuery. This setup might require the use of a service account.

Related

- [Create a development environment and use a deployment tool for Google apps script in spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38359874/1595451)
- [Best development setup for developing gmail add-ons locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50621565/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In general set up, the developers have restricted access to GCP project and its mostly with DevOps. Setting up GCP project ID in App Script project requires you to be editor of a project which is not possible in my case. I can get that set up one time for a dev project and use it for my development. Is this a recommended approach? Is there any way I can test it without all this?

Comment: I suggest you to post a new question proving a [mcve].